# The difference of vertical advection and convection process for chemistry species

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmospheric-chemistry, air-quality

In atmospheric, the change of mixing ration $C_i$ of a chemical species $i$ is determined by:

$\frac{\partial C_i }{\partial t} = -\bigtriangledown (VC_i)+\frac{\partial  }{\partial z}(k_z\frac{\partial C_i }{\partial z}) + (\frac{\partial C_i }{\partial z})_{dry}++ (\frac{\partial C_i }{\partial z})_{wet}+(\frac{\partial C_i }{\partial z})_{conv}+P_i-L_i+E_i$

1. The first term represent the $Ci$ change due to horizontal and vertical advection.
2. The fifith term on the right hand represent the $Ci$ due to the vertical convection.

I have read about this question ["What exactly is the difference between advection and convection?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24489/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-advection-and-convection/118738#comment539944_118738).

The answer told, which I quoted:

> Advection is the movement of some material dissolved or suspended in the  fluid.
>   Convection is the movement of a fluid, typically in response to heat.

But when we are just talking about the chemical species. They are not in fluid form. So,how dos the convection process mean?

Update:  The equation was from a phD dissertatio *Climate and Air Pollution Modeling in South America focus on Megacities*. Links [here](https://www.mpimet.mpg.de/fileadmin/publikationen/Reports/WEB_BzE_76.pdf)

Comment: Conv = Convective Precipitation? Wet could only mean non-convective precipitation.

Comment: Could you give a reference to the equation?

Comment: why aren't the chemical species in fluid form?  aren't they subject to the same movement?

Comment: @farrenthorpe. In my opinion, chemical in particular phase were also included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between advection and convection in Chemistry Transport models (CTMs) is a question of scale:

- **Advection** is driven by winds that are provided by the meteorological input dataset. Thus, the wind is resolved in the meteorological data.
- **Convection** is driven by sub grid processes (e.g. temperature gradients) and is paramterized in CTMs.

See for example:

- Pleim, 2007a. doi: [10.1175/JAM2539.1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/JAM2539.1)
- Pleim, 2007b. doi: [10.1175/JAM2534.1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/JAM2534.1)
- Rasch et al., 1997. doi: [10.1029/97JD02087](http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/97JD02087)